# How can I create a function to draw a sprite on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create function `sprite()` with `canvas` in `javascript`
I have 2 codes
this to create a sprite :

```
var width = 40,
    height = 28,
    frames = 2,

    currentFrame = 0,

    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image = new Image()
    image.src = 'http://s28.postimg.org/k90gybbtl/bird_Sprite.png';

var draw = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, height * currentFrame, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

    if (currentFrame == frames) {
      currentFrame = 0;
    } else {
      currentFrame++;
    }
}

setInterval(draw, 120);
```

I have another code for simple game :

```
function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myUpBtn = new component(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", 0, 0); 
    myGameArea.start();
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
      this.image = new Image();
      this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
                if (type == "image") {
                    ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                    this.x, 
                    this.y,
                    this.width, this.height);
                } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
    }
        this.clicked = function() {
        var mytop = this.y;

        var clicked = true;
        if (mytop > myGameArea.y) {
            clicked = false;
        }
        return clicked;
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
} // https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_images.asp
```

etc... 
now the problem is ...

I can't make the 2 codes together

can anyone help me?

thank you :)

Comment: The source code of the game: [HTML Game](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp) ..
With some edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code adds your sprite to the game code from W3 Schools:

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(40, 28, "red", 10, 120, "sprite");
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;

    if (type === "sprite") {
        this.currentFrame = 0;
        this.frames = 2;
        this.tickCount = 0;
        this.ticksPerFrame = 4;
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = 'http://s28.postimg.org/k90gybbtl/bird_Sprite.png';
    }

    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else if (this.type == "sprite") {
            if (this.tickCount > this.ticksPerFrame) {
                ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, this.height * this.currentFrame, this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

                this.tickCount = 0;

                if (this.currentFrame == this.frames) {
                    this.currentFrame = 0;
                } else {
                    this.currentFrame++;
                }
            } else {
                ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, this.height * this.currentFrame, this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                this.tickCount++;
            }
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startGame()">
  <br>
  <button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
  <p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
  <p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
```

In summary:

- Within the `component` function we initialise variables to handle the sprite animation if the `type` parameter is set to `sprite`
- Within the `update` function we only draw the next frame of the sprite animation every 4th time `update` is called. This ensures that the sprite animation doesn't play to quickly
- We then increment or reset the `currentFrame` count the same as you did before in your original code
- If we're not ready to display the next frame in the sprite animation, we just display the existing frame again.

To take it further you might want to consider refactoring my solution so that the sprite is a separate "class" which inherits it's core functionality from `component`.